# Script returns error only when ran by Cronjob

Tags: php, curl, cron

We have a script in PHP that downloads external images using CURL (CURL PHP library: https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class), when ran directly as the user owner of the file it works with no problem (SSH), but when it is executed by the cronjob (which according to me should be the same user) we get a warning:

```
PHP WARNING: curl_setopt(); 
supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle
```

This is the code we are running where the warning is generated:

```
  public function setOpt($option, $value){
       $required_options = array(
         CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => 'CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT',
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER',
       );

    if (in_array($option, array_keys($required_options), true) && !($value === true)) {
      trigger_error($required_options[$option] . ' is a required option', E_USER_WARNING);
    }
    $this->options[$option] = $value;
    return curl_setopt($this->curl, $option, $value);
 }
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: 1. What are the arguments given to this function when it fails? 2. Are you setting CURL_FILE? 3. Does the user account you're running this as have the proper permissions to that file? 4. Are you using relative paths? 5. Is the CWD of the script what you think it is when cron runs it?

Comment: Hi Sammitch, the user has all permissions, CURL_FILE is set,  all paths are absolute, the CWD shouldn;t affect as all paths are absolute. Thanks.

Comment: var_dump each setOpt function call parameters until you can pinpoint which one is throwing the error.